# Javascript sort function in different browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Hello I have this javascript function to sort the items in ascending order with zero value at the bottom, in Chrome and Firefox work properly, while in Edge, Explorer and Safari null values are not placed at the bottom, but I have to do a check. Why should I do this, there is a problem in my function?

```
var items = $('.UCSceltaCamere').find('.bloccoCamera');
items.sort(function (a, b) {
        var price_a=0;
        var price_b=0;
        //get value only if element has availability
        if ($(a).find(".SelezionaCamereNoDisponibilità").length == 0 ) {
            price_a = Number($(a).find("[id*='priceRoomMin']").val());
        }

        if ($(b).find(".SelezionaCamereNoDisponibilità").length == 0) {
            price_b = Number($(b).find("[id*='priceRoomMin']").val());
        }
        //is null
        if(price_a===0){
            return 1;
        }
        //is null
        if(price_b===0){
            if(isIE || isEdge || isSafari){
                return -1
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        }

        return price_a-price_b;

    });
$('.UCSceltaCamere').append(items);
```

Comment: Please put a runnable [mcve] in the question using Stack Snippets, along with a clear explanation of the expected results.

Comment: Note: `0` and `null` are not the same thing.

Comment: I use 0 for detect the element that must going at end what is the difference in using 0 or null for identificate those elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a default value for sorting to the end.

```
return (price_a || Infinity) - (price_b || Infinity);
```

Togther

```
items.sort(function (a, b) {
    var price_a = 0;
    var price_b = 0;
    //get value only if element has availability
    if ($(a).find(".SelezionaCamereNoDisponibilità").length == 0 ) {
        price_a = Number($(a).find("[id*='priceRoomMin']").val());
    }

    if ($(b).find(".SelezionaCamereNoDisponibilità").length == 0) {
        price_b = Number($(b).find("[id*='priceRoomMin']").val());
    }

    return (price_a || Infinity) - (price_b || Infinity);
});
```